# Linux - How to kill kibana process

Tags: kibana

How to kill/stop Kibana process ?

Answer (score 10):

Answer: **netstat -pln | grep 5601** 
then you can get the process id and **kill -9 13304** 
[image: netstat command]

Comment: it seems "netstat -pln | grep 5601" is not returned the PID if you dont use sudo

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed as service following command will work

```
service kibana stop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kill -9 `ps aux|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'`
```

is very helpful when you find a lot of Kibana processes. But be careful that it can kill other processes that contain "kibana" in the process name.